# Ubuntu20.4 keeps closing on install

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

I have installed the Ubuntu20.4 packages on my windows 10 machine and successfully unpackaged to reveal the Ubuntu.exe file. Upon execution of the Ubuntu.exe file the ubuntu terminal will launch, and without any error message closes again. This is stopping me from completing the Ubuntu installation.

I have removed all packaged and re-downloaded, essentially starting from scratch but this has not seemed to help.

Please advise what I should do as this is blocking me from taking on some important tasks.

Comment: Some info missing, some incorrect. Do you mean 20.04? And you are trying to run it under WSL? Are you using WSL1 or WSL2? How did you install it? Is this on x86-64?

Comment: Please add details on how exactly you tried to install, the way you describe seems extremely uncommon. Using WSL or running a full Ubuntu installation in a Hyper-V virtual machine are the common and proven to work ways.

Comment: @LiamProven I did mean 20.04, running under WSL1, installed by downloading the distribution from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-6---install-your-linux-distribution-of-choice 
specifically the Ubuntu 20.04 (Non-ARM) and then unzipped and attempted to install via .exe file. My system is X64. Hope that clarifies things?

Comment: @ayush Better, but this is still not clear. (1) WSL1 is legacy tech now; WSL2 is current. Ubuntu 20.04 is also legacy; 22.04 is current, and will be replaced in <6 months. So, why these old versions? (3) *How* did you download and install WSL, and how did you download and try to install Ubuntu? I have done this myself and I never got a file called `ubuntu.exe` -- that does not sound right to me.